# cant get Value of radio buttons in php when form is submitted

Tags: php, html

So I am using a form multiple radio buttons, The purpose is for the user to rate different parts of the site with 10 questions.

The user presses "start rating" button and the 1st question appears, then the 2nd etc.
When he finishes all of the 10 questions a submit button appears.

The problem is that, when I'm trying to retrieve these values on PHP, I get nothing, its like the radio buttons hasn't been pressed at all.

Newbie in HTML.

HTML

```
<form name="f1" action="rate.php" method="POST">
        <!--1η ερώτηση-->
        <div class="question_div" id="question_div1">
            <center><p class="questiontitle"><b>Ερώτηση 1 από 10</b></p></center>
            <p>Νομίζω ότι θα ήθελα να χρησιμοποιώ αυτά τα παιχνίδια συχνά.</p>

            <div class="answer_div">
                <div class="answer_options">
                    <label class="opt_label">
                        <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_1" value="1" class="option">
                        <span class="opt_span"><b>1</b></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="opt_label">
                        <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_2" value="2" class="option">
                        <span class="opt_span"><b>2</b></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="opt_label">
                        <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_3" value="3" class="option">
                        <span class="opt_span"><b>3</b></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="opt_label">
                        <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_4" value="4" class="option">
                        <span class="opt_span"><b>4</b></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="opt_label">
                        <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_5" value="5" class="option">
                        <span class="opt_span"><b>5</b></span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="answer-options">
                    <div align="left" style="width:20%;
                                             float:left;
                                             margin-right:30px;">Διαφωνώ απολύτως</div>
                    <div align="right" style="width:20%;
                                              float:right;
                                              margin-left:30px;">Συμφωνώ απολύτως</div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <button class="nextbtn" type="button" id="btn1" onclick="(function(){
                                                                                    document.getElementById('question_div1').style.display = 'none';
                                                                                    document.getElementById('question_div2').style.display = 'block';
                                                                                    return false;
                                                                                })();return false;">Επόμενη Ερώτηση</button>

        </div>
```

this is the start of the form and the 1st question, the other questions follow the same architecture.

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST["f1"])){
    $q1 = $_POST['input1'];
    $q2 = $_POST['input2'];
    $q3 = $_POST['input3'];
    $q4 = $_POST['input4'];
    $q5 = $_POST['input5'];
    $q6 = $_POST['input6'];
    $q7 = $_POST['input7'];
    $q8 = $_POST['input8'];
    $q9 = $_POST['input9'];
    $q10 = $_POST['input10'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have the same `<input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1_1" value="1" class="option">` with the same `name` value. Try removing the `name` a attribute in your `<form>` and do one radio first and in your php file do this:

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action='rate.php'>
    <div> question </div>
    <input type="radio" name="input1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

rate.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input1']) {
    echo $_POST['input1'];
    //do your code here
}
```

Comment: I have the same name because there are more than 1 answers in the questionarie which the user must choose from . As i checked on internet this is a valid syntax when you have more than 1 options.

Comment: I just checked what you said and everything works correct with only one unique name , how i must procceed so i can have more than 1 answers ? just different names on each?

Comment: Oh so you might as well put it in an array like `name="input1[]"`  then from that you can loop. have you tried the solution I propose? does your form submit?